# Drawing text labels for CToolBar buttons -- different for Windows 7/10 and Windows XP

Tags: mfc, toolbar

I am creating a vertical toolbar (CToolBar, Visual Studio 2015 with XP toolset) with text buttons. Below is code (somewhat abbreviated for simplicity) that draws text labels (font is created to draw text vertically).

There is no problem when the application runs in Windows 7 or 10 but in Windows XP the background to the text labels is white.

Is there a problem with the code that causes the white background for Windows XP?

See images below (top image is Windows 7 or 10 screen capture, bottom is Windows XP screen capture):

[image: Windows 7 or 10]
<sub>(source: [koolmoves.com](http://www.koolmoves.com/temp/stackexchange/verttoolbar_win7.png))</sub>

[image: Windows XP]
<sub>(source: [koolmoves.com](http://www.koolmoves.com/temp/stackexchange/verttoolbar_winxp.png))</sub>

```
// code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19653/How-to-Create-a-Dynamic-ToolBar
m_dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
m_hBitmap    = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc->m_hDC, nWidth, nHeight);
m_pBitmap    = CBitmap::FromHandle(m_hBitmap);
m_pOldBitmap = m_dcMem.SelectObject(m_pBitmap);

//draw a filled rectangle with the background (window) color 
CRect rect(0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);
FillRect(m_dcMem.m_hDC, &rect, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW));

m_dcMem.SetMapMode(MM_TEXT);
m_dcMem.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
m_dcMem.SetTextColor(RGB(68, 68, 68));

//
... use m_dcMem.TextOut to draw text
//

if (m_pOldBitmap != NULL)
    m_dcMem.SelectObject(m_pOldBitmap);

m_dcMem.DeleteDC();

SetBitmap(m_hBitmap);
```